# Ruby : uploaded files suddenly become not found within hours in heroku

Tags: java, ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have the following post code for Ruby Sinatra to upload image files :

```
post "/upload" do 
  File.open("public/uploads/" + params["image"][:filename], "wb") do |f|
    f.write(params["image"][:tempfile].read)
  end
end
```

And the following Java codes to upload the image file to example.com/upload :

```
private static String boundary;
private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
private static HttpURLConnection httpConn;
private static OutputStream outputStream;
private static PrintWriter writer;

public static void upload(String requestURL, String fieldName, File
uploadFile) throws IOException {

    boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"), true);

    String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Type: "+ URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName)).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    inputStream.close();

    writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.close();
    httpConn.getInputStream();
    httpConn.disconnect();
}

File uploadFile = new File("C:/myimage.png");
upload("http://www.example.com/upload", "image", uploadFile);
```

And my website is hosted at heroku .

After calling upload(), the image file is successfully uploaded, and i can access to it in example.com/upload/myimage.png

But the problem is : After some hours, when i check the url to see myimage.png, i got "Not Found" error ( 404 error in heroku logs )

Any ideas ?

Sorry for my bad english :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not store files to heroku's local file system. From their [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Ephemeral filesystem
>
> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with
>   a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s
>   lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary
>   scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in
>   any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the
>   dyno is stopped or restarted.

Instead of storing files locally it is recommended to upload files to AWS S3 or other cloud storage systems.